# Tensorflow dataset download in Colab using Python 3.8+ for waymo data set

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying

```
!pip3 install waymo-open-dataset
```

in Colab, but I get

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement waymo-open-dataset (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for waymo-open-dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
**Note:** you should put your dependencies installation in another cell as it will help you narrow down problems that is related to python code or dependencies installation

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install waymo-open-dataset-tf-2-0-0==1.0.1 --user
```

Comment: It just took to long to download the Waymo data set since it is 336 GB of data. I instead switched to similar content just in the range of  33 GB from Kaggle rather than from the bucket on Google Cloud.  This is how I solved my problem but not necessarily the one I was asking originally. I will still be looking for a solution for waymo data for future models.  Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Hi, as the topic of this question is to solve the error, I beleive this answer should receive an answer mark. About the solution for download the waymo effectively, I think it would fit another question

Comment: Additionally, there is great tutorial for ultilizing the dataset: https://github.com/waymo-research/waymo-open-dataset/blob/master/docs/quick_start.md that I think might be helpful per your need